# FluentUI in a ScriptLab

Tags: office-js, office-addins, fluent-ui, javascript-intellisense, scriptlab

In my new ScripLab's project I am trying to add a reference to the library FluentUI by the following code:

`@fluentui/web-components@2.5.16/dist/web-components.min.js`

But I get an error in the console:

> ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'", "https://unpkg.com/@fluentui/web-components@2.5.16/dist/web-components.min.js", 240, 3412, SyntaxError]

What should I write in Libraries sections in order (1) to use FluentUI web components in my project and (2) to get IntelliSense for it